# Is it correct to talk about a "lost age"?

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to talk about a "`lost age`"?

In the sense of a long gone era, or a time where an extinct civilization was living for example.

Edit : I will not use this expression as part of a sentence or speech, but more as a title to describe a universe, a project.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you think might be wrong about 'lost age'?

Comment: I am not a native english speaker, and I have not found a lot of references in which it is used. I just needed to make sure it can be used. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is **no, it's wrong**.  It is not idiomatic, and sounds a bit "weird".

You're thinking of "lost civilisation", say.

It doesn't make much sense to talk of a "lost" age.  (How could it be "lost"?)  You're thinking more of a "bygone age" (or more commonly, "bygone era").

Or for instance there's a common phrase "those days are gone forever."

Note too that "golden age" or "golden days" is very common.

[image]

(Title card from the most famous and most-watched film in English.)

Again, if you say "lost age" it (a) doesn't make much sense and (b) sounds like a confusion of other common phrases.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I should have precised it but I will not use it as part of a sentence or speech, but more as a title to describe a universe, a project. The main relevant reference I could find is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Sun:_The_Lost_Age). In this case, it seems to be understood and to make sense.

Comment: hope it helps...

Comment: It does, but I am quite confused. I understand it is not commonly used, or even incorrect in a way... but can it be used in the context I described above? Would it sound "weird"?

Comment: You're asking an incredibly subtle question.  You're now saying **"Does it work as the title of a Japanese video game"**  Indeed it sounds a little "Japanese english" -- you know what I mean?  You can keep asking over and over :)  But the answer to your question is, yes, it sounds "a bit weird" in English. Pls note sentences 2 3 and 4 of my answer above: those apply, exactly, to that video game title.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Considering the effort put in, please "vote up" this and any answers which give you useful information.

Answer (score 1):

It's not incorrect, per se. But it's not a typical expression in the sense that you describe. It's more common to see the expression "bygone era."  You might also see the word "age" paired with modifiers, such as "during the age of enlightenment" for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's a somewhat poetic way of phrasing the concept. You're more likely to encounter it in a book, or in a speech, than in ordinary conversation. But most native speakers should understand it.